# PHP - get properties of an object in an array?

Tags: php

I have an multiple array ($result) which has objects in it. The array was returned from a function (made by someone I can't communicate now).

When I test the array with print_r($result[0]), it turns out to have embedded objects.

```
ABC Object ( 
    [p1] => P1 Object ( 
        [p1-1] => P1_property1 
        [p1-2] => P1_property2 
        [p1-3] => P1_property3
    ) 
    [p2] => ABC_property2 
    [p3] => ABC_property3 
    [p4] => ABC_property4
)
```

How can I fetch the Strings `"P1_property1"` to `"P1_property3"` and `"ABC_property2"` to `"ABC_property4"`?

I'm new to PHP, waiting for help!

Comment: and it doesn't work to use `$result[0]['p1']['p1-1']`?

Comment: @hovmand: Not if it's an object, and not an array.  It'd have to be `$result[0]->p1->{'p1-1'}`

Comment: @Rocket: Of course, will this work too? `$result[0]::p1::p1-1`, and why the brackets around p1-1?

Comment: @hovmand: That's not what `::` is used for, it's for `static` properties.  The brackets are because `->p1->p1-1` would be a problem because of the `'-'`.

Comment: @Rocket Thanks a lot!! this work, also, $result[0]->{'p2'} is for the properties not embedded in an object. Thanks for the clever tip.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), which will return an array of accessible properties.

```
class foo {
  public $bar = "foo";
  private $bor = "fizz";
}

$properties = get_object_vars( new foo() );

print_r( $properties );
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [bar] => foo
)
```

Comment: Thanks! but I wanted to just to get the string of the properties. the comments below my original question works great.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this to figure out what the contents of those variables are:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($result[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks! but I wanted to just to get the string of the properties. the comments below my original question works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
This function return all the properties in a class

function get_object_public_vars($object) {
    return get_object_vars($object);
}
```

Comment: This has been given in the other answers already - what's the need of duplicating them?